# Date d = Calendar.getTime() returns wrong time?

Tags: java, date, calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(calendar.HOUR, 8);
calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, 45);
calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 00);
    
Date d = calendar.getTime();
    
System.out.println(d);
```

Output is:
Wed Oct 05 20:45:00 BST 2011

Can anyone help me with why this is?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Calendar.HOUR`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) is used to set the hour as set on a 12-hour clock.

In other words, you **do** set the `Calendar` to 20:45. It's 8:45 **PM**.

Use [`Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) to set the 24-hour-clock value.

Answer (score 8):

Sure - you're setting [`Calendar.HOUR`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) which represents the 1-12 "hour of half day". You should be using [`HOUR_OF_DAY`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) which is the 0-23 value for the whole day:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
```

Alternatively, use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which is a much nicer date/time API :)

As an aside, *please* don't refer to static members via references... it will lead to pain when you call `someOtherThread.sleep(...)` and your current thread sleeps...

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                            .withHour(8)
                            .withMinute(45)
                            .withSecond(0)
                            .toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DCUpHA)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

**Note:** Most likely, you would like the *fraction-of-second* too to be zero. If yes, just add `.withNano(0)` in the existing code as shown below:

```
OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .withHour(8)
    .withMinute(45)
    .withSecond(0)
    .withNano(0)
    .toInstant();
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>